# Testing a static variable in a function with PHPUnit

Tags: php, static, phpunit

I have the following simplified code to test, which is an included function in our library that controls rendering for many different devices.

```
<?php
    define('CHROME_18_0_HTTP_USER_AGENT',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.152 Safari/535.19');

    define('FIREFOX_13_HTTP_USER_AGENT',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0');

    define('FIREFOX_16_HTTP_USER_AGENT',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0');

    define('IE_8_HTTP_USER_AGENT',
            'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)');

    define('IE_9_HTTP_USER_AGENT',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)');

    define('OPERA_11_5_HTTP_USER_AGENT',
            'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50');

    define('SAFARI_5_0_HTTP_USER_AGENT',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27');

function IsIe()
{
    static $IsInternetExplorer;
    if (!isset($IsInternetExplorer))
    {
        $Server = array_key_exists('HTTP_USER_AGENT', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'UNKNOWN';
        $IsInternetExplorer = ((strpos($Server, 'MSIE') === FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE);
    }
    return $IsInternetExplorer;
}

/**
 * @backupGlobals enabled
 */
class TEST_IsIEFunctions extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $backupGlobals = TRUE;

    public function UserAgentDataProvider()
    {
        return array(
            'Chrome 18'  => array(CHROME_18_0_HTTP_USER_AGENT, FALSE),
            'FireFox 13' => array(FIREFOX_13_HTTP_USER_AGENT, FALSE),
            'Opera 11'   => array(OPERA_11_5_HTTP_USER_AGENT, FALSE),
            'Safari 5'   => array(SAFARI_5_0_HTTP_USER_AGENT, FALSE),
            'IE 8'       => array(IE_8_HTTP_USER_AGENT, TRUE),
            'IE 9'       => array(IE_9_HTTP_USER_AGENT, TRUE),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @backupGlobals TRUE
     * @dataProvider UserAgentDataProvider
     */
    public function testIsIeFunction($UserAgent, $IsIeResult)
    {
        $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = $UserAgent;
        $this->assertEquals($IsIeResult, IsIe());
    }
}
?>
```

Error Output:

```
Q:\>phpunit TestIe.test
PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

....FF

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.50Mb

There were 2 failures:

1) TEST_IsIEFunctions::testIsIeFunction with data set "IE 8" ('Mozilla/4.0 (comp
atible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
 .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322;
 .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', true)
Failed asserting that false matches expected true.

Q:\TestIe.test:60

2) TEST_IsIEFunctions::testIsIeFunction with data set "IE 9" ('Mozilla/5.0 (comp
atible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)', true)
Failed asserting that false matches expected true.

Q:\TestIe.test:60

FAILURES!
Tests: 6, Assertions: 6, Failures: 2.
```

I am running PHPUni 3.7.13 with PHP 5.4.11, 5.3.22.

I have tried setting the various versions of the backupGlobals (comment section and protected variable) to TRUE and FALSE without success.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update:
Also tried the backupStaticAttributes with the commented @backup and protected $backup

Comment: You are accessing `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in your test but it will be not available. (or at least not contain useful information)

Comment: I am setting it though, and validating that it is set.  This value would normally be set in a web page where our code is running, so the code uses that variable.  For my test, I am setting it to see that code can check the value.  This all words correctly, if I remove the 'static $IsInternetExploer;'.  If I allow the code to check the variable without it being saved via the static, the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] does get set and evaluated properly.